# how to deal with unused bitmap object?

Tags: android, bitmap, resources

My application needs creating a bitmap object for a certain view every 1 min

```
private static Bitmap mBitmap = null;

public static Bitmap getBitmap()
{
   //create new bitmap object
   return mBitmap;
}
```

My question is, do I need to destroy mBitmap before creating new bitmap ?

Comment: No, on recent Android version you don't have to do anything. But on older devices the developers had to manually release the memory by calling `recycle()` on the `Bitmap`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to manually destroy a `Bitmap` after you used it, but you can help the garbage collector do its job. There is a method called `recycle()`, the following paragraph is from [**its documentation**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle()):

> Free the native object associated with this bitmap, and clear the
>   reference to the pixel data. This will not free the pixel data
>   synchronously; it simply allows it to be garbage collected if there
>   are no other references. The bitmap is marked as "dead", meaning it
>   will throw an exception if getPixels() or setPixels() is called, and
>   will draw nothing. This operation cannot be reversed, so it should
>   only be called if you are sure there are no further uses for the
>   bitmap. This is an advanced call, and normally need not be called,
>   since the normal GC process will free up this memory when there are no
>   more references to this bitmap.

In earlier Android versions `Bitmaps` were handled natively by the OS. This was the original reason for the `recycle()` method. Since the `Bitmaps` were handled outside of the Java VM the garbage collector could not automatically free the memory of unused `Bitmaps`, you can find more information about that [**here**](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html) but the important part is this:

> On Android 2.3.3 (API level 10) and lower, the backing pixel data for
>   a bitmap is stored in native memory. It is separate from the bitmap
>   itself, which is stored in the Dalvik heap. The pixel data in native
>   memory is not released in a predictable manner, potentially causing an
>   application to briefly exceed its memory limits and crash. As of
>   Android 3.0 (API level 11), the pixel data is stored on the Dalvik
>   heap along with the associated bitmap.

So if you want to support Android 2.3.3 (Gingerbread) or below you have to be careful with `Bitmaps`. You always have to remember to call `recycle()` otherwise your application may crash in an unpredictable manner.

If you only support Android versions above Android 3.0 then you don't have to worry about freeing `Bitmap` memory, but if you create a lot of `Bitmaps` and/or are getting close to `OutOfMemoryExceptions` then calling `recycle()` on all not needed `Bitmaps` can still have 
a considerable positive effect.

If you want to learn more about handling `Bitmaps` then visit [**this link**](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html).

I hope I could help you and if you have any further questions please feel free to ask.

Comment: So you are not going to accept and/or upvote an answer? I'm just asking because if you want more or a different kind of information you have to tell me.

Answer (score -1):

You should never do that, you should either:

- Reuse the Bitmap if size is always the same (clearing and reusing)
- Caching bitmaps using an LRU cache

If you absolutely need to destroy it every time call Bitmap.recycle() and then create a new one, but this is a very very bad thing to do.

Comment: Calling `recycle()` is everything but a bad thing. It is absolutely necessary on Gingerbread and below and still has a positive effect on devices above Gingerbread. `recycle()` releases the resources associated with the `Bitmap` and helps speed up the garbage collection.

Comment: Off course its good to call recycle(), what i meant is that its absolutely bad to recreate a new bitmap at every draw!